# Error in this php code calculation not sure it does not produce the expected results

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run this code to give me the percentage of two whole numbers.
The code gives me the correct percentage, but does not round the result to a whole number.
*For example*: 84.33333 to 85.

I am new to PHP and have been unable to create the right code to round up or down for that matter, I have tried floor and ceil.

```
($result['sales']) / ($result['appointments']) *100, round(0.05)
```

Any help to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to round your fractions up then use `ceil` function.
Eg:

```php
<?php
echo ceil(4.3);    // 5
echo ceil(9.999);  // 10
echo ceil(-3.14);  // -3
?>
```

If you want to round your number to some pre-defined fractions then use `round` function. 
`round` function have a second parameter called `precision` which can be used for this purpose.

Eg:

```php
<?php
var_dump(round(3.4)); // float(3)
var_dump(round(3.5)); // float(4)
var_dump(round(3.6)); // float(4)
var_dump(round(3.6, 0)); // float(4)
var_dump(round(1.95583, 2)); // float(1.96)
var_dump(round(1241757, -3)); // float(1242000)
var_dump(round(5.045, 2)); // float(5.05)
var_dump(round(5.055, 2)); // float(5.06)
?>
```

You will get more information from the PHP Docs. Links below.

[PHP Ceil Function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php)
[PHP Round Function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)

For your specific case it will be like below:

```php
$percentage = ( $result['sales'] * 100 ) / $result['appointments'];
$percentage_rounded = ceil($percentage);
var_dump($percentage_rounded); exit;
```

Comment: I was not thought about logical errors. I was just suggesting the PHP functions and how it works. Actually, you have logica error in your code. 
If you want to calculate a percentage of a number then it would be like `$percentage = ( $result['sales'] * 100 ) / $result['appointments'];`. I have updated my answer to reflect this. Please check.

Comment: In the above code, the variable `$percentage` stores the percentage without rounding, and the variable `$percentage_rounded` stores the rounded value.

Please print the `$percentage_rounded` to get the rounded value.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help your answers not only solved my problem but also helped me understand code logic a little better.

Comment: Take your time and be sure to understand how it works exactly. So that you can use them in future and improve. Glad to hear!

Answer (score 0):

the function you're looking for is `ceil(84.3333)`

see [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php)